# Speeding up sampling of Gaussian entries

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to speed up sampling from the projected Gaussian distribution (like Gaussian, but vectors normalized to have norm 1). Code below generates $d$ samples of size $d$ and it's about 300x slower than sampling from standard normal for $d=2000$.

Any suggestions how to reduce this overhead?

```
d = 2000;

normalizedGaussianSampler[diag_] := 
  With[{d = Length[diag]}, 
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
    vals = Sqrt[diag]*# & /@ 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}];
    #/Sqrt[Total[#*#]] & /@ vals]];

sampler = normalizedGaussianSampler[Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}]];
sampler[d]; // AbsoluteTiming (*{21.170401`,Null}*)
RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[], {d, 
    d}]; // AbsoluteTiming (* {0.083068`,Null} *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the examples for [`Compile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html). Whenever you define some new symbols inside your function, you should make them locally scoped by using `Module`. Otherwise, the compiled function has to transfer the values (in your case `vals`) back to the main evaluator, which takes a lot of time.

```
normalizedGaussianSamplerFixed[diag_] := 
  With[{d = Length[diag]}, Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    Module[{vals},
     vals = 
      Sqrt[diag]*# & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}];
     #/Sqrt[Total[#*#]] & /@ vals]
    ]];

samplerFixed = normalizedGaussianSamplerFixed[Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}]];
samplerFixed[d]; // AbsoluteTiming 
(* 0.165976 *)

RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}]; // AbsoluteTiming 
(* 0.135395 *)
```